# Ember event on window close

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When a user closes the browser, I want to run some code before the window gets closed out, because if not it causes problems for other users. Part of the application I'm working on has a random video chat. The room is created by a user and while they're waiting for someone to join they close their browser tab/window and then the room is not closed out correctly and still open for another user to join.

I've seen many examples using beforeunload, but they just aren't working for me with Ember. Maybe I'm missing a more ember way of doing things, or maybe I need to rely on a heartbeat approach?

What I've been trying to do is use the window beforeunload event, but I haven't been having any luck. If there is a better way to go about solving my above problem, I'm all ears!

Right now I bind the method in the setupController such as:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  console.log('ending chat');
  this.endChat();
});
```

I've also tried this code in the route, and maybe in the view (tried so many things over the past month that I don't remember everything).

UPDATE: Code update

Here is the setupController referring to the controller object instead of the window.

```
setupController: function(controller, hash){

    $(window).on('beforeunload', () => {
      controller.hasStarted ? controller.endChat() : controller.send('leaveChat');
    });

    $(window).on('click', () => {
      controller.hasStarted ? controller.endChat() : controller.send('leaveChat');
      console.log('you just clicked');
    });
}
```

The window click event fires perfectly, but nothing happens on the beforeunload event - the window just closes normally without firing any action/method.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `endChat` defined? The way you currently have it written, `this.endChat()` is scoped to the window. I'm guessing you want it scoped to the controller or route.

If you're using Ember CLI, you can use fat arrow syntax to remain in the outer scope like this:

```
// routes/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function () {
    $(window).on('beforeunload', () => {
        this.endChat();
    });
  },

  endChat: function () {
    // do the thing
  }
});
```

If not, then you can do it the old fashioned way:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function () {
    var _this = this;

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
        _this.endChat();
    });
  },

  endChat: function () {
    // do the thing
  }
});
```

Does that work?

Comment: it's close! Yeah the events are on the controller. I've changed it but can't get any action on the beforeunload event. I added another event to the window click event to verify that everything is hooked up correctly, and that works. But still nothing on beforeunload

Answer (score 0):

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
 setupController: function () {

    Ember.$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e){
        e.returnValue = "hi";
        return e.returnValue;
    });

  }
```

});